# Yii CFileCache seem not delete expired cache

Tags: php, caching, yii

I seem to have some problem when using CFileCache in Yii. It seem doesn't delete the expired cache automatically.

Here is my configuariton in main.php:

```
    'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
        'embedExpiry' => true
    )
```

here is how I set the cache in my controller with 30 seconds expired time:

```
 Yii::app()->cache->set("mykey", "somedata", 30);
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration or my code? I really need this to be solve.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `CFileCache`, you can use the following things to clear the cache

1. `Yii::app()->cache->flush();`. This will remove all the Cached data, ie the files from the folder 'runtime'.
2. `Yii::app()->cache->gc();`. This will only remove the expired cache data

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by delete?
As per the API description provided in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache if the data item expires then `get` will return false. Did you run the `get` method after 30 sec and check for the return value?

Comment: I mean with the garbage collect which I read in the API which say something like this: "CFileCache will perform garbage collection automatically to remove expired cache files. "

Comment: Did you try the `gc()` method?

Comment: Did you figure this out?